# How to test before_create method with Rspec in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

In my user model I have a function that generates an account ID for the user. I would like to write a test that creates a user (I'm using FactoryGirl) then checks to ensure the account_id field isn't empty after the user is saved.
With my current test I'm getting an error that says the following:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_not=' for #<RSpec>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_account_id

  private

    def generate_account_id
      self.account_id = loop do
        random_account_id = rand.to_s[2..6]
        break random_account_id unless self.class.exists?(account_id: random_account_id)
      end
    end
end
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
#spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    user = create(:user, :user)
    expect(user).to be_valid
  end

  it "receives a Account ID on successful create" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    expect(user.account_id).to_not == nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is due to a typo: "undefined method" means you're calling something that doesn't exist. In this case, Ruby's interpreting your `.to_not ==` call as an attempt at assignment. If you check [the RSpec documentation for `==`](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers#compare-using-==), you'll find it uses the `be` method as well:

```
expect(user.account_id).to_not be == nil
```

Alternatively, your test might be clearer if you [use the `be_nil` matcher instead](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers#be-nil-matcher):

```
expect(user.account_id).to_not be_nil
```

---

The other aspect of this problem is you're using `build`, not `create`. [FactoryGirl's build method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) (see section "Using factories"), much like [ActiveRecord's](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/build), doesn't save the object. As a result, the `before_create` callback won't fire.

Comment: That type fixed things in terms of syntax. However, I'm thinking my code isn't the proper way to test callbacks. I received the following `Failure/Error: expect(user.account_id).to_not be_nil expected: not nil got: nil` It seems like the callback isn't being called with my test block.

Comment: That's a bug in your code. :) [FactoryGirl's `build` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) (see section "Using factories"), much like [ActiveRecord's](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/build), doesn't save the object. As a result, the `before_create` callback won't fire.

Comment: You're right :). I changed it from build to create and the test is passing now. Do you want to add that change to your answer so I can accept? Thanks for the help.